# Understanding this algebraic manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was watching this lecture on limits and the lecturer did the following algebraic manipulation:

$$
\begin{align*}
 &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ \sqrt{x^2-4x+1} + x }{1-4x} . \frac{ \frac{1}{x} }{ \frac{1}{x} }
\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} } + 1 }{ \frac{1}{x} - 4 } 
\end{align*}
$$

The part I didn't understand is how $\frac{1}{x}$ multiplied with $\sqrt{x^2-4x+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we know that as long as $x$ is positive, then $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}= \frac{1}{x}$ 
We also know that $\sqrt{a} \times \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$ 
Thus, $\frac{1}{x} \times \sqrt{x^2-4x+1} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}} \times \sqrt{x^2-4x+1} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2} \times (x^2-4x+1)} = \sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}$ 
I believe you have a typo and accidentally wrote $-\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: Check the first term in your final expression.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I'm not used to LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.. and pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{x} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
and for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ $$\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$$

Comment: Thanks.. didn't thought about hint before.